# Duplicate content penalty for adding event information to sidebar widgets?

Tags: seo, wordpress, google-ranking

I have an entertainment-based WordPress site. If I place my upcoming events on the sidebar via widgets that will contain links and event information, they will appear both on my home page and internal pages.

Will the upcoming events rank in search engines will my web site be penalized?

Answer (score 1):

Google's algorithm's are smart enough to know when a site is using a sidebar to display repeated content and you will not suffer a duplicate content penalty for displaying event information there.

As to whether or not the algorithm will rank you well, that's a question that we can't answer because indexing/ranking is the result of numerous variables.